# What's the use of exports / module.exports?

Tags: angularjs, browserify

Today I've adopting Browserify for my AngularJS project, but there is something that's very unclear to me. In all examples and blog posts I've seen stuff like this:

#### /app.js:

```
require('./messages');
angular.module('sling', ['sling.messages']);
```

#### /messages/index.js:

```
exports = angular.module('sling.messages', [])
    .controller('MessagesListCtrl', require('./MessagesListCtrl'));
```

#### /messages/MessagesListCtrl.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    // ...
});
```

---

Sure, this works, but why do this? I've implemented it like this and that works absolutely fine too and feels more normal for an AngularJS project:

#### /app.js:

```
require('./messages');
angular.module('sling', ['sling.messages']);
```

#### /messages/index.js:

```
angular.module('sling.messages', []);
require('./MessagesListCtrl');
```

#### /messages/MessagesListCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('sling.messages').controller('MessagesListCtrl', function() {
    // ...
});
```

In other words, I'm completely skipping the exports/module.exports, only using `require` to basically include the files with the controllers, services, filter, etc.

Am I doing this right? I mean it all works, but am I going to be in trouble later on?

Comment: http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/. Don't know why your code does work, maybe browserify concatenates your code & it "works" because everything is in the right order(?)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The main (and honestly only) reason to use Browserify is if you want to have CommonJS modules (i.e. NodeJS modules) in the browser. A CommonJS module stays out of the global scope by having an implicit 'module' scope. You choose what to expose from the module scope (usually the entry point or primary function of your module) into by augmenting the 'exports' object that every module has.

So a 'real' CommonJS module looks like this.

File A:

```
// a.js

function doSomething() {
  console.log("I am doing something");
}

module.exports = doSomething
```

File B:

```
// b.js

doSomething();
// Exception - attempt to call a non-existent function
```

File C:

```
// c.js
var doSomething = require('a');
doSomething();
// logs "I am doing something"
```

In the browser which has no module scope, `a.js` would be augmenting the global scope with the doSomething function, since it's declared as a global. Browserify works around this by wrapping each bundled module into a function wrapper, and supplying an 'exports' object to the included modules as an argument to this wrapper.

Enter AngularJS. You've got two approaches you can use here, of which I'm assuming from the fact that you're not using require('angular') is the first:

1. Include AngularJS as a hard-coded script available in your index.html *before* your Browserify-transpiled bundle script.
2. Shim AngularJS so that it is attached to an exports object rather than the window (using something like [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)), then importing it using require like any other module.

I tend to prefer the second approach because it's kind of weird to use Browserify to give you module scope and then make the major dependency of your project a window global.

However, AngularJS already has its own dependency-injection driven module system. When you declare angularJS components, you're attaching them to module objects which themselves have been attached to the `angular` object. This means that the `exports` object for your angularJS module files is essentially redundant in the case of Angular, since as long as the file executes then the `angular` object will be augmented with your module and components.

You still need to 'require' the files since otherwise Browserify won't bundle them, they'll never execute, and they'll never augment the `angular` object with your modules. But you don't *need* to add anything to the exports for Angular, since the `angular` object is your exports.

So why did I spend all this time explaining how CommonJS modules and exports work? Because hopefully the *other* reason why you are using Browserify is to allow you to make use of modules hosted on NPM in your browser application. Most of those modules are non-angular commonJS modules, meaning their functionality is exposed via an exports. In this case it's important to capture their exports in a variable when you require them, such as I'm doing in `c.js` above. Similarly, if you write some modules and release them to NPM, your users are going to expect you'll be adding the entry point to your module to the `exports` object of the file declared as main in your `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I actually dropped Browserify and am simply using bower, gulp and concat (+ sourcemaps). Much simper, does what I need.

Comment: Note while browserify uses CommonJS as its default, it also has support for AMD and ES6 style module definition - http://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html

Comment: I think something that is missing here is that Browserify has the ability to recursively include the correct modules without the developer needing to known (explicitly needed to set) which ones are needed.

Comment: +1 Best explanation I found on stack overflow, and not afraid to talk about redundancy of using browserify with angular.js.